# GraphQL and .NET No object implementing interface problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, graphql

I have GraphQL Interface like this:

```
using SmartBuilding_GraphQL.Models;
namespace SmartBuilding_GraphQL.IService
{
    public interface IRoomService
    {
        List<RoomValues> GetRoomInfos();
    }
}
```

and implementation like this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SmartBuilding_GraphQL.IService;
using SmartBuilding_GraphQL.Models;

namespace SmartBuilding_GraphQL.Service
{
    public class RoomService : IRoomService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<RoomService> _logger;
        private readonly SmartBuildingDbContext _dbContext;

        public RoomService(ILogger<RoomService> logger, SmartBuildingDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }
        public List<RoomValues> GetRoomInfos()
        {
            //RoomValues output = new RoomValues();
            //var room =  _dbContext.Rooms.Find(valueId);

            return _dbContext.Rooms.ToList();

                //output.ValueId = room.ValueId;
                //output.CO2 = room.CO2;
                //output.Temperature = room.Temperature;
                //output.Humidity = room.Humidity;
                //output.Light = room.Light;
                //output.Timestamp = room.Timestamp;

        }
    }
}
```

In Models folder Query.cs looks like this:

```
using SmartBuilding_GraphQL.IService;
using SmartBuilding_GraphQL.Models;

namespace SmartBuilding_GraphQL.Models
{
    public class Query
    {
        IRoomService _roomService = null;

        public Query(IRoomService roomService)
        {
            _roomService = roomService;
        }

        public IRoomService Get_roomService()
        {
            return _roomService;
        }

        public List<RoomValues> GetRoomValues()
        {
            return _roomService.GetRoomInfos();
        }
    }
}
```

I have problem when I want to execute any query in Postman to get any data from Microsoft SQL Server database. It says that there is no object type implementing interface IRoomService (picture below).

I would be very grateful if anyone can help or suggest how to solve this problem!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the implementation to a dependency injection container? You can read more about it here [hotchocolate/dependency-injection](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/server/dependency-injection)